# running a mysql stored procedure from php

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, stored-functions

I must be doing something wrong in this code....

```
<? 
$codeid=$_GET["codeid"];
$tablecode=$_GET["tablecode"];
$description=$_GET["description"];
$code=$_GET["code"];
$groupcode=$_GET["groupcode"];
$t1=$_GET["t1"];
$t2=$_GET["t2"];
$t3=$_GET["t3"];

$mysqli = new mysqli(dbhost,dbuser,dbpass,dbc);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

$q="call spUpdateCodeTable(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
$stmt->bind_param($codeid,$tablecode,$description,$code,$groupcode,$t1,$t2,$t3);
$stmt->execute();

mysql_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Absolutely nothing happens...no error message or any other indication of a problem.  It just does not run the procedure. (it's an update/insert routine).

I am using this URL...

```
updateCodeTable.php?codeid=0&codetable=TABLE&desription=testing2%20entry&code=TEST1&groupcode=gcode&t1=t1&t2=t2&t3=t3
```

...but, if I run the this query in phpMyAdmin, it runs perfectly....

```
call spUpdateCodeTable(0,'TABLE','testing2','TEST1','group','','','');
```

I could include the stored procedure code, but it runs fine anytime I run it directly, but just not running successfully from my php code.

Comment: try again with `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); $q="...` - makes it harder to miss sql errors. see http://docs.php.net/mysqli-driver.report-mode

Comment: May I ask, why you are using a procedure?

Comment: Because I am a long time ms-SQL server guy where stored procedures do most everything.  I still have the opinion that as much processing that can be done on the server, should be.  But new to php and MySQL, so who knows what I will think a year from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each mysqli* function/method can fail. Either test the return values and/or switch the reporting mechanism to exceptions, see http://docs.php.net/mysqli-driver.report-mode

```
<?php
// probably better done with http://docs.php.net/filter but anyway ...just check whether all those parameters are really there
// you are positive that GET is the correct method for this action?
if ( !isset($_GET["codeid"], $_GET["tablecode"], $_GET["description"], $_GET["code"], $_GET["groupcode"], $_GET["t1"], $_GET["t2"], $_GET["t3"]) ) {
    // die() is such a crude method
    // but bare me, it's just an example....
    // see e.g. http://docs.php.net/trigger_error
    die('missing parameter');
}
else {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(dbhost,dbuser,dbpass,dbc); 
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $q="call spUpdateCodeTable(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);
    if ( !$stmt ) {
        // $mysqli->error has more info
        die('prepare failed');
    }
    // you have to provide the format of each parameter in the first parameter to bind_param
    // I just set them all to strings, better check that
    if ( !$stmt->bind_param('ssssssss', $_GET['codeid'], $_GET['tablecode'], $_GET['description'], $_GET['code'], $_GET['groupcode'], $_GET['t1'], $_GET['t2'], $_GET['t3']) ) {
        // $stmt->error has more info
        die('bind failed');
    }

    if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
        // $stmt->error has more info
        die('execute failed');
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you find it quite excessive?

Comment: Your Common Sense : I have a hunch by `quite excessive` you don't mean the quality of the code ;-) but the "doing the work of others" part. Quite frankly I've given up on refering to the good practices in hope everyone learns them extensively, never happens. So I'm just content with mabye, just maybe raising the baseline on some aspects and not letting too many people go away with _awfully_ localized answers still unaware of the huge stack of _fundamental_ flaws in their scripts. Wish there was a "burn after reading" vote for questions and answers on SO. I'd mark most of my answers as such.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will do a bit more investigating returning error info.

Comment: The problem turned out to be in the calling URL.  The second parameter was suppose to be 'tablecode' but I had 'codetable'.  Fixed that and it ran like it should.  I did learn a bunch about validating and error trapping and I really thank you about that.

Comment: In that case just another observation: You are using GET as the transport method yet your stored prodcedure is called `spUpdateCodeTable`, so apparently data from the client is used to change data in your model/database. In that case you should use POST instead of GET, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29

Comment: I have used GET and POST both over the years, and for the most part, I use POST. Not sure why I set this up as GET, but at the time, I was just trying to understand the process of using AJAX in the PHP / MYSQL environment.  I agree that POST is a better method to use, but that was of secondary concern when experimenting with this.

Answer (score -1):

May you have a try to this?

```
mysqli->query("call spUpdateCodeTable($codeid,'$tablecode',
 '$description','$code','$groupcode','$t1','$t2','$t3')");
```

Comment: This would defeat the whole purpose of using a prepared statement

Comment: Amit:  Yes, that is what I would have done before, but I am trying to learn to use prepared statements.  I can't even tell you the advantages of using them right now except that I have read that is what seems to be preferred right now.  In this case, though, the problem was a typo rather than the logic.

Comment: ...I should say, the problem was a typo AND my lack of error checking.